# Hour averaging program

Tags: c++, homework

I am looking for tips on improving my short program.  I am using `system("PAUSE")` because this was for an assignment.

[image]

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void Display(string* , int* , double*, int);
void Percentage(int*, double*, int);
void Intro(string*, int*, int&);
void Highest(int&, string&, double*, string*, int);

int main()
{
    int students;
    string names[10];
    int hours[10];
    double percents[10];
    int highest;
    string most;


    Intro(names, hours, students);

    Percentage(hours, percents, students);
    Display(names, hours, percents, students);

    Highest(highest, most, percents, names, students);

    system("PAUSE");
}


void Intro(string* names, int* hours, int& students)
{
    int team;
    cout << "A team is made up of atleast 2 students. How many students are on the team?: ";
    cin >> team;

    cout << "Enter student's first name and the hours worked on the final project: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < team; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> names[i] >> hours[i];
    }

    students = team;
}

void Display(string* names, int* hours, double* percent, int students)
{
    cout << setw(20) << "Students";
    cout << setw(20) << "Hours Worked";
    cout << setw(20) << "% of Total Hours";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(20) << names[i];
        cout << setw(9) << hours[i];
        cout << setw(16) << percent[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void Percentage(int* hours, double* percent, int students)
{
    int total(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        total += hours[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        percent[i] = double(hours[i]) / total * 100;
    }
}

void Highest(int& highest, string& most, double* percent, string* names, int students)
{
    highest = percent[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        if (highest < percent[i])
        {
            highest = percent[i];
            most = names[i];
        }
    }

    cout << most << " worked the most hours." << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `getchar()`...

Comment: @tintinmj: `std::cin.get()` would be preferred for C++.  It also goes with `<iostream>`, whereas `getchar()` goes with `<cstdio>`/`<stdio.h>`.

Comment: Your "% of Total Hours" column doesn't line up with its header.  Should be a simple enough thing to do properly, and it just looks sloppy if you don't.

Comment: I realized, this was because I added an extra symbol last minute.

Comment: @Jamal yeah right... I overlooked the `C++` tag!

Comment: @tintinmj: You were still on the right track (hence the votes). :-)

Comment: @Justin have you really to stick to arrays in this homework?

Comment: @Wolf Yes. It was part of the assignment.

Comment: What a pity! Were at least structs allowed? If yes, then the `struct Student` idea will also help a lot.

Comment: Nope, the class hasn't been "taught" struct and classes yet. I would use them, but I don't want to get marked off.

Comment: @Wolf: This is why I tread carefully with homework questions (I've only made references to vectors in my answer).  The OP can always go back and improve on them later, but we should also not provide too much information since this is for a grade.  Either way, it's important to keep in mind that even homework questions should be beneficial to site visitors (otherwise they may be considered too localized).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- I assume you'll have no more than 10 names/hours/percents, but you could use an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in place of these arrays.  This will allow you any number of inputs without fear of exceeding the allotted 10.  If you don't need this for your assignment, then you can stick with what you have.
- If you're allowed to use more of the STL, I'd recommend [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) for summing up the values in a container.

  For instance, your first loop in `Percentage()`:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
  {
      total += hours[i];
  }
  ```

  can be done with this function as such (with the array):

  ```
  // the 10 corresponds to the array size
  // the 0 is the starting value of the accumulator

  int total = std::accumulate(hours, hours+10, 0);
  ```

  If you choose to use `std::vector` (or other STL container):

  ```
  // functions cbegin() and cend() return const iterators

  int total = std::accumulate(hours.cbegin(), hours.cend(), 0);
  ```
- I'd slightly tweak the percentage calculation for clarity:

  ```
  percent[i] = (double(hours[i]) / total) * 100;
  ```
- Prefer to cast the C++ way:

  ```
  // C way
  double(hours[i])
  ```

  ```
  // C++ way
  static_cast<double>(hours[i])
  ```
- It seems a little weird having `Highest()` display something.  You could instead return `most`, thereby making the function of type `std::string`.  That way, you can display this name from `main()` or wherever else.

  You don't need the first two arguments.  They are passed in from `main()`, but also not modified by any previous functions.  I'd remove those two and just use local variables.

  `highest` should be of type `double` since it's being assigned to a `percent` element.  Otherwise, you may receive a "possible loss of data" warning.  This is especially important for when the two values are being compared in the loop.

  You could then have this:

  ```
  // get the name
  std::string most = Highest(percents, names, students);

  // display it
  std::cout << most << " worked the most hours." << std::endl;
  ```

  ```
  std::string Highest(double* percent, string* names, int students)
  {
      double highest = percent[0];
      std::string most;

      for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
      {
          if (highest < percent[i])
          {
              highest = percent[i];
              most = names[i];
          }
      }

      return most;
  }
  ```

Comment: @Jamal I would consider your `percent[0]` dereferencing before the loop a little dangerous. Even if the homework states that at least 2 students form a team, I would not trust in this.

Comment: @Wolf: This is what the OP has in the code, minus the numerical types.  That apecific part I didn't look at closely.  I suppose this means that the entire program should use vectors instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: Yes, nobody can learn all at one time. And the OP obviously didn't ask for a vector tutorial.

Comment: @Wolf: Right, but it could still help to mention it, even if it cannot be used in this assignment.  Heck, I'm not opposed to going back to old assignments and improving on them.  Many can make great references!

Answer (score 10):

To add to what [Jamal is saying](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/35945/31651). If you are allowed to used basic structs, you could do something like this:

```
struct Student
{
    std::string name ;
    int hours ;
};

static void Intro (std::vector <Student> &students) ;
static void Display (const std::vector <Student> &students) ;
// ...
```

This way, you don't have to manage parallel arrays.

Comment: D'oh!  I forgot all about `struct`s.  I was merely going by the OP's solution, but this could also work.  +1 from me.

Comment: And then there are more good options like giving that struct an `operator>>` or similar helper method...

Comment: Great answer (from the *code review* POV). I think, you agree in this, that the percentage shouldn't be stored along the real input, which is name and hours?

Comment: @Wolf, Yeah I agree. Percentage information would be redundant. A function should be used to calculate that information.

Answer (score 2):

Again, in addition to [jliv902's addition](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/35946/31651) - and since we are here for code review - I think the `Highest` function needs only names and hours (and therefore `std::vector<Student>` which I shorten as `Students` via `typedef`):

```
typedef std::vector<Student> Students;

std::string Highest(const Students& students)
{
    int highest = 0;
    std::string most = "nobody";

    for (Students::const_iterator i=students.begin(); i!=students.end(); ++i) {
        if (highest < (*i).hours) {
            highest = (*i).hours;
            most = (*i).name;
        }
    }
    return most;
}
```

So also `percents` are for output only and need not to be stored along with the real input. As a pragmatic introduction to `std::vector`, the according `Intro` function will do best:

```
void Intro(Students& students)
{
    int teamSize = 0;
    cout << "A team is made up of atleast 2 students. How many students are on the team?: ";
    cin >> teamSize;

    cout << "Enter student's first name and the hours worked on the final project: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < teamSize; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << ": ";
        Student s;
        cin >> s.name >> s.hours;
        students.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

**BTW:** Would you be satisfied with a solution, where two or more students **share the first place in hours** but only one of them is put out as the top worker?

**EDIT**: this simple approach allows for a list of top workers instead of single one:

```
typedef std::list<std::string> Names;

/// output the name(s) of the student(s) that have worked the most hours
Names HighestList(const Students& students)
{
    int highest = 0;
    Names result;

    for (Students::const_iterator i=students.begin(); i!=students.end(); ++i) {
        if (highest < i->hours) {
            highest = i->hours;
            result.clear();
            result.push_back(i->name);
        } else if (highest == i->hours) {
            result.push_back(i->name);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `Highest()`'s parameter should also be `const` (and the iterators could also be `.cbegin()` and `.cend()`).  It would also be more readable to use `i->hours` instead of `(*i).hours)`.

Comment: I've also never considered initializing `most` with "nobody", which seems pretty obvious now.  Can't possibly identify every little point, though. ;-)

Comment: @Jamal Oh, good point, I only forgot to remove this assignment I casually added. ;-)

Comment: For `Highest()`, using `std::max_element` from `algorithm.h` would be better than rolling your own loop.

Comment: @jliv902 good idea, indeed. What about adding your own appendix? I'll better not to incorporate this suggestion, because it cannot handle the problem with the shared top rank.